# Textbox for Logmessages HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

Before creating an own solution I tried finding something which already suits my needs. I have got a node.js server where multiple clients / applications connect to. These clients will send log messages to the server which I would like to display in a panel.

Now there are some feature I that I need for a **typical multiline textbox for logmessages**:

- I need to be able to append log messages as they will be send regularly via websockets
- It should autoscrolldown unless the user is selecting text or scrolling up
- It should be able to use colors and bold/regular

**My question:**

Is there already a solution for the above use case?

Comment: something like: `ta.value+=msg.body+"\n"; ta.scrollTop=9e9;`

Answer (score 2):

Can I give you my [example](http://users.telenet.be/tive/)? It used to be a `textarea` but I've refactored it to a `div` with little code changes.

Some highlights of the code, available on [github](https://github.com/timver/Yambo)

A custom function to **send log messages**:

```
/**
 * Add a message to the gamelog
 * @param {Object} options : allows custom output
 * @param {String} options.message : the message to display
 * @param {Boolean} options.isTimed : does the message has a timestamp in front of it?
 * @param {Boolean} options.isError : is the message an error?
 * @param {Boolean} options.isNewline : start the message on a new line
 */
addMessage: function (options) {
    var instance = ns.instance,
        audio = instance.audio,
        audiofx = audio.settings.fx,
        history = this.areaMessage.html();

    // isTimed?
    options.message = options.isTimed
        ? history + this.fieldClock.val() + ': ' + options.message
        : history + options.message;

    // isNewline?
    if (options.isNewline) {
        options.message = options.message + '<br />';
    }

    // message
    this.areaMessage.html(options.message);
    this.scrollTop(this.areaMessage);

    // isError?
    if (options.isError) {
        audio.play(audiofx.error);
    }
},
```

A **scroll to top** function:

```
/**
 * Automatically scroll down (from the top)
 * @param {Object} target : jQuery object
 */
scrollTop: function (target) {
    target.scrollTop(99999);
    target.scrollTop(target.scrollTop() * 12);
}
```

To use **colored messages** you should be able to use an HTML string:

```
log.addMessage({
    message: '<span style="color: red;">[ERROR]</span>&nbsp;',
    isNewLine: false
});

log.addMessage({
    message: 'the rest of the error message',
    isNewLine: true
});
```

Feel free to use this idea to enroll your own custom message box.

Comment: that could get slow in yuge logs; better to appendChild than clobber all the rich html each update...

Comment: Ye, you might be right! Only need this to survive one game so to speak.
Btw, I like your golf version ^^

Comment: @TimVermaelen after taking some more time for your suggestion I noticed that this is not entirely what I am looking for as I am missing some options as stop autoScrollDown when someone scrolledUp and formatting content (like single words) inside of the text area (your suggestion won't work). I guess I will create a bounty and hope that someone knows a library which solves this use case. I am convinced a lot people have already faced a similiar issue

Comment: Fair enough, although I'm curious why HTML format won't work.